# How can I call a member function on an Array with two parameters?

Tags: function, symfony, doctrine, entity

in my Controller:

```
$relationEntity  = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Data::class)->findPosition($dataId,$documentId);
$relationEntity->setContent("hello");
```

in my Repository:

```
  public function findPosition($dataId,$documentId) {

    return $this->createQueryBuilder('data')
                    ->leftJoin('data.documents', 'dd')
                    ->andWhere('dd.uuid = :documentId')
                    ->andWhere('data.document_id = :dataId')
                    ->setParameter('documentId', $documentId)
                    ->setParameter('dataId', $dataId)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->execute();
}
```

I get the error message:

> Call to a member function setContent() on array

I know that it would work with `findOneby`but then I cannot find the entry I want to edit by two parameters. So I am not sure what to do now.

Comment: Var_dump your variable and see what you can do next.

Comment: I tried, but there is no output

Comment: the output is empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
foreach ($relationEntity as $r) {
     $r->setContent("hello");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use [custom repository](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/doctrine/repository.html) you should return getResult() istead of execute, try this:

```
    $datas = $this->createQueryBuilder('data')
                    ->leftJoin('data.documents', 'dd')
                    ->andWhere('dd.uuid = :documentId')
                    ->andWhere('data.document_id = :dataId')
                    ->setParameter('documentId', $documentId)
                    ->setParameter('dataId', $dataId)
                    ->getQuery()
                    ->getResult();
    return $datas[0];
```

If you are sure of query return only one row, you can return first result.

Comment: Thank you! I tested it and still `Call to a member function setContent() on array`

Comment: @monkeylove i change return in answer, but be sure that return only one row